# Get job script directory with SGE

Tags: hpc

With the Sun Grid Engine, how can I get the directory where the job script is located, within the job script?

I need this so I can start the script with

```
cd script-location
```

to make sure it'll have access to all the necessary files.  So far I have hard-coded the script directory into each script, which makes it much too easy to make mistakes.

Comment: You can find out your current working directory using the PWD environment variable. Also, an absolute path for `script-location` should ensure you change to the right directory, regardless of your working directory when the script starts (you're already doing this). Is that what you're looking for? I typically code in paths using environment variables, if possible, to make hacking scripts easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#$ -cwd` option to your job script will guarantee that SGE places you in the submission directory automatically so that you don't have to do `cd script-location` manually. The environment variable `SGE_O_WORKDIR` is defined and available to your job script as the working directory that you submitted it from as well.

These and other things are described in the man page for qsub.

Comment: I found `-cwd`, but I misunderstood it as referring to the locations of the `job.o*` and `job.po*` files.  `SGE_O_WORKDIR` sounds like it should definitely work.  Of course everything is documented somewhere, but it's not always obvious where (google is usually better than a man page, but apparently not in this case) ... and experimenting with job scripts is both tedious and frustrating because of the waiting time.  Thank you for the answer!

Comment: My pleasure. I didn't mean to be snarky about the man page. Just marking it for future reference for others.